# C# connection to firebird failed by IP, succeeded by hostname

Tags: c#, firebird2.1

I have a very weird issue: about C# connection to Firebird.
Look at the string below, and just check the DataSource parameter:

```
User=SYSDBA;Password=masterke;
Database=c:\\example\\example.fdb;
DataSource=hostName;Port=3050;
Dialect=3;
Charset=ASCII;Role=;
Connection lifetime=0;
Connection timeout=15;
Pooling=True;
Packet Size=8192;
Server Note=0


If DataSource=hostname, it works fine.
if DataSource=192.168.X.X, I got: Unable to complete network request to host "192.168.X.X"
```

Can any one help?

Comment: is the database setup for `NamedPipes as well as IP`

Comment: [Connection Strings FireBird](http://www.firebirdfaq.org/faq260/)

Comment: Thanks. Don't know what it means. Any tip?

Comment: don't know what what mean..? click on the link and you will see examples

Comment: I used name & IP address in IBExpert, they worked fine.

Comment: Oh got it. I am sure my connection string is a via TCP/Ip protocol. Here is it: 192.168.16.37:c:\MyS\MyServer\exe, this one does not work

Comment: If I use: davidPC:c:\MyS\RMyServer\exe. It works fine.

Comment: sounds like it's configured to use named pipes..

Comment: Hi DJ KRAZE, I'd like to change the configuration for test. How can I do that?

Comment: @DJKRAZE The .net connector - by default at least - doesn't use named pipes; it is a re-implementation of the Firebird wire protocol.

Comment: When I tested the connection from IBExpert, I specified TCP/IP, not NamedPipes. The working string: davidPC:c:\MyS\RMyServer\exe also follows the TCP/IP protocol. I am stuck here.